# How to call a function inside the success in SWAL using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

Second function is not working. It doesn't received the id that being passed from the first function.

Here is my JQuery code.

```
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this record!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    cancelButtonText: "No, cancel!",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
    },
    function(isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) {
      // this.$http.delete();
      window.axios.post(`/delete-sl-gl/${brcode}/${slc}/${slt}/${sle}/${cts}`)
        .then(response => {
        // console.log(response.data.sle)
          if (response.data.success === true) {
            swal('Deleted', response.data.message, 'success'); 
            //console.log(response.data.sle)
            spliceSLE_gl(sle.sle);
          }

        })
        .catch(error =>{
        console.log(error.response)
        });
    } else {
      swal("Cancelled", "Your file is safe :)", "error");
    }
```

I got an error / ignored in **spliceSLE_gl(sle.sle);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [swal](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) instance is a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Description). To add functions based on user action, you have to use the `then()` method.

Here is the structure of a swal with chained [catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) and [then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) methods.

```
swal({
    // The swal configuration params
  })

  // To avoid getting a "cancel" if user click the close button
  // or clicks on the overlay (outside the swal)
  // "noop" means "no operation".
  .catch(swal.noop)

  // To handle the confirm/cancel buttons
  .then(function (result) {
    if (result) {
      // Your "confirm" function
    }
    if (!result) {
      // Your "cancel" function
    }
  });
```

Comment: where do i put this    spliceSLE_gl(sle.sle);? this what i want to call after the SWAL success..

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more obvious where to add functions. Have a look. ;)

Comment: thanks i already solve it.. i have new problem in splicing table row child.. 
glcontrol => data 1 
             data 2
             cts => (this is a child array inside data2)

this won't work
var gl = glcontrol.find(g => {
      return g.GLControlSLE_CODE == sle
          })
    console.log(gl.cts);
    var found = glcontrol.cts.find(c => {
      return c.GLControlCTS_NUM == cts
    })
    if (found) {
      var index = gl.cts.indexOf(found)
      gl.cts.splice(index, 1)
    }
      displayCts(sle)
any idea @Louys?

Comment: No idea... It does not look like JavaScript.

Comment: i already solved it @Louys. I missed conditions in swal. by the way do you have email? so that i can directly ask you if i have problem in my code.