# Proper way to make a soft delete using sweetalert2

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, sweetalert2

Hello guys I'm using sweetalert2, this is already function but there are some bugs that need to be fix.

bugs:

1. When I click ok the `location.reload()` will be triggered without hitting "OK".
2. When I click cancel the modal is still in popup mode.

This is my script.

```
$('body').on('click','.delete-category',function(){
            deleteCategory();
        });

        function deleteCategory(id){

           var id = $('body').find('#categoryTable tbody tr.selected .catId').val();
           console.log(id);

            swal({
                title: 'Are you sure?',
                text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
            }).then(function(isConfirm){
                if (isConfirm) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: `/asset/category-delete/${id}`,
                        method: 'DELETE',
                        data: { _token: '{{ csrf_token()}}' },
                        success: function(data){
                            swal(
                                'Deleted!',
                                'Your file has been deleted.',
                                'success' 
                            );
                            location.reload();
                            },
                        error: function(err){
                            swal('Error!','Please report this issue.', 'error');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                swal("Cancelled","", "error");
                }
            });
        }
```

Looking for enhancement.

Comment: What do you mean by this `when i clicked ok the location.reload() will automatically running without hitting OK`? How did you clicked ok without clicking OK? Also can you reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: when i click delete button it should prompt a message ok or cancel, when i click ok, it will automatically run the location.reload() function without hitting ok in my second swal  swal(
                                'Deleted!',
                                'Your file has been deleted.',
                                'success' 
                            );..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your bug #1: You have to place `location.reload();` in a `then()` method if you want if to be executed after a swal interaction.

```
success: function(data){
  swal(
    'Deleted!',
    'Your file has been deleted.',
    'success' 
  ).then(()=>{
    location.reload();
  });
},
```

About your bug #2: I can't figure out what *«delete modal»* you talk about...

Comment: Thanks men, then() is what i missed.

Comment: I have the other problem... when i click cancel or outside the page this function  swal(
                                'Deleted!',
                                'Your file has been deleted.',
                                'success' 
                            ).then(()=>{
                                location.reload();
                            }); will still executed..

Comment: I mean when you click cancel.... the location.reload() will still executed.

Comment: Look at this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51492405/2159528) of mine...

Answer (score 0):

I found example you can handle cancel by HANDLING DISMISSALS link given below

```
swalWithBootstrapButtons({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
  cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
  reverseButtons: true
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    swalWithBootstrapButtons(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  } else if (
    // Read more about handling dismissals
    result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.cancel
  ) {
    swalWithBootstrapButtons(
      'Cancelled',
      'Your imaginary file is safe :)',
      'error'
    )
  }
})
```

This [link](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#handling-dismissals) help you