# Delete with SweetAlert & Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need delete a record from a DataTable, but I need a confirmation with SweetAlert, how to made this? thanks

My code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-delete", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(resp){
            window.location.href = base_url + resp;
        }
    });
});
```

This is my record in a DataTable, and the button btn-delete:

[image: DataTable]

Comment: Instead of redirecting when the ajax call finishes, have you sweet alert callback do the redirect.

Comment: And where is the Sweet Alert code? Have you tried to implement it?

Comment: I don't have idea how made it

Comment: Well.. Start by reading the [documentaion](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples)... At least.

Comment: This [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51492119/how-to-call-a-function-inside-a-swal-success-in-jquery/51492405#51492405) may help... But only if you read the basics first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".btn-delete", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    url = $(this).attr("href");
    swal({
            title:"Do you want delete this item?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
            buttonsStyling: false,
            confirmButtonText: "Delete",
            cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        },
        function(isConfirm){
            if(isConfirm){
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(resp){
                        window.location.href = base_url + resp;
                    }
                });
                }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: I upvoted... You did well by yourself ;) You can accept your own answer, in order to remove it from the "active" questions... I think there is a 2 days delay though.